# con WPF en c# soy nuevo y quiero una lista observables con ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf

```
 Private _ListaCategoria As New ObservableCollection(Of Categoria)
```

Esto es Visual Basic. ¿Como seria la declaración en C# es una colección observable o una lista?

Answer (score 0):

```
private ObservableCollection<Categoria> _ListaCategoria = new ObservableCollection<Categoria>();
```

Comment: Para que funcione habrá que incluir el using System.Collections.ObjectModel;